# groovy script is unable to find file in resources

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a `gradle` application with a structure like this

```
src\main\
        antlr\
        groovy\
            jvm\
                script.groovy
        java\
        resources\
            program.pas
```

In my script I have a line

```
CharStream input = new ANTLRFileStream("program.pas")
```

I run script using this task

```
task runScript(dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'jvm.script'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

But when I do that I get `FileNotFound` exception for `program.pas`.
When I move to the root of the project - it is able to find it.

My built structure looks like this

```
build\
    classes\
        main\
            jvm\
                script.class
    resources\
        main\
            program.pas
```

Why it is unable to locate in resources?

Comment: Why is your script not in a package folder if you've declared it as so? Try `"/program.pas" `

Comment: my bad. while editing message I removed it. Did not help. Same message `filenotfound: \program.pas`

Comment: Well. Something is definitely wierd. It is unable to find in script imported classes from `java` folder.

Comment: Yeah, it will compile the groovy first and of course the Java isn't there yet. You can just move your Java files into src/main/groovy.

Comment: @tim_yates, wait. Default behavior of groovy plugin should be `java first`. Why it compiles groovy first?

Comment: Because it compiles the groovy first

Comment: @tim_yates, I did build, then `runScript` and it worked fine. The reason it was not able to find `java` classes was actually rather weird. My classes had names like `pascalLexer` and etc. And when I tried to run as `pascalLexer pl  = new pascalLexer()` it could not find method `pascalLexer` inside script - simply because `pascalLexer pl` looked like a method invokation for him lol! When I changed it to `def pl = new pascalLexer()` it started to work.

Comment: Classes should start with a capital letter